# Mount a new partition to existing mount point

Tags: linux, mount, partition

Similar question has [already been asked on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/191299/can-we-mount-multiple-disks-as-one-directory) but I have a slight difference that might create issues if I follow already answered question's solution, therefore I must make sure.

The idea is for the `/var/www/html/`  directory to show files that are present in `/mnt/a/www/html/` as well as the files that currently reside in `/var/www/html/`.

I have a 4TB HDD mounted as `/var`. The space on this HDD is almost up, which is why I added another 4TB HDD that is not mounted yet. What I plan to do is create a mount point for this new HDD `/mnt/a/` for example and then use `mhddfs` utility to merge `/var` and `/mnt/a`  into a single mount point of `/var` with possibly following command:

```
mhddfs /var/,/mnt/a/ /var/
```

So that the two HDDs both have a single mount point of `/var` and no restart of the server to be necessary. 
Does `mhddfs` support executing such command when the resulting mount point is the same as one of the *to-be-merged* mount points? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You're unlikely to be able to mount a filesystem on top of another one and still use the underlying one. I'd suggest you test that carefully before going anywhere near your `/var`.

Comment: It is this one https://serverfault.com/questions/191299/can-we-mount-multiple-disks-as-one-directory

Comment: Well, https://github.com/trapexit/mhddfs says categorically, "_##PLEASE DON'T USE THIS## mhddfs is buggy, unsupported, and has some major security issues._". That's a pretty good reason not to use it.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware mhddfs had such issues. They recommend mergerFS as an alternative that supports performing the same task, however my original concern of doing such merger still stands.

Comment: The only difference to the related question is that your existing HD is mounted as `/var` and you want to appear the merged file system at `/var`. Why not simply change the mount point of your existing HD to e.g. `/var1` and mount the new HD as `/var2` and merge these two as `/var`?

Comment: Does anything speak against using symlinks and - in case your contents change very often - inotify to update the symlinks? (`ln -s /mnt/a/www/* /var/www/`)

Comment: @Bodo That is precisely what I am testing currently on a virtual Linux distro. I am, however, concerned for possible bottlenecks when using mergerFS in terms of speed.

Comment: As mentinoned in an answer to the linked question, https://serverfault.com/a/191324, the correct solution would be to create a logical volume and copy all data to the logical volume. Then you are able to add physical volumes later. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in comment, using `mhddfs` on a critical production system looks to be a bad idea.

The good way to solve your problem would be using LVM2. Below are the steps:

1. Create a new LVM Volume Group (`vgcreate`) that used your new hard drive.
2. Create a new LVM Logical Volume (`lvcreate`) from the previously created Volume Group.
3. Format the Logical Volume using a filesystem that support resizing.

At this point, you have a clean, 4TiB filesystem.
Then, i would:

1. Mount the new filesystem to a temporary location (let's say `/var-tmp`).
2. `rsync /var /var-tmp`.

At this point, you have a copy of your old `/var` on `/var-tmp`.
Then:

1. Stop every services relying on `/var`.
2. `umount /var`.
3. Mount your new, LVM based FS on /var instead.
4. Restart services.

At this step, you have `/var` relocated to your new hard drive.
Then:

1. Use `pvcreate` to prepare your old HDD to be used on your LVM2 Volume Group.
2. Use `vgextend` to add it to your Volume Group.
3. Resize your FS.

Now you have a 8TiB `/var`.

**NOTE**: umount /var may be a bit complicated since several system daemon relies on it. 
If your system refuse to do so, you'll probably have to put it offline for a few minutes but, if well prepared, the unavailability of your system  can be very short.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I followed your suggestion exactly and did create a LVM logical volume, moved `/var` onto it, merged the old HDD using `pvcreate` and `vgextend`, and afterwards resized the FS to use 100% free space using `lvextend` and got this [output](https://ibb.co/MsrwwR7) from `lsblk`, where `/dev/sdb` was the old HDD and `/dev/sdc` is the new one (virtual HDDs, 4GB in size each). However, `df` [shows](https://ibb.co/g3fHFQt) that the lvm volume has 4GB available and I am unable to create a file bigger than 4GB in `/var`

Comment: I forgot that apart from resizing the LVM I had to also resize the filesystem using `resize2fs` for example. Afterwards `df` showed the correct size and all went well. You have my thanks, kind sir.

Comment: You're welcome :-)